# Getting the title of the page in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm experimenting with PhantomJS. Here is a simple code which does not work as expected. After running it I can see in the console `success` and `foo` but the document's title is an empty string.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://www.google.com', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    console.log("foo");
    console.log(document.title);
    phantom.exit();
  }
});
```

Comment: (1) Have you tried taking a screenshot (`page.render()`) to see if the page event loaded? (2) Which PhantomJS version do you have? (3) Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: (1) yes, and the pic is ok. (2) I have just downloaded the latest 2.0.0 version (3) I added the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` code from the example, but no error at all. here is my full js file: http://pastebin.com/hYmXzryW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to get the title is to use [`page.title`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/title.html).

The reason `document.title` doesn't give you anything is because PhantomJS has two distinct contexts. Only the page context (inside of [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)) has access to the DOM and therefore the `document` object. The outer context also has a `document` object, but it doesn't do anything and is therefore only a dummy object. The same goes for `window`.

So the other way to get the page title is to use:

```
console.log(page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.title;
}));
```